# Can you use Conll-U formatted files for neuralcoref training?

Tags: nlp, spacy, conll, coreference-resolution

This
[guide](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref/blob/master/neuralcoref/train/training.md) shows how one can train the **neuralcoref** package using Conll-2012 formatted files. I have prepared Conll-U formatted files using the **spacy_conll** package. Does anyone know if one can use Conll-U files for neuralcoref training instead? Does anyone have any experience with said package? Thank you very much.

Comment: The CoNLL format used for coref annotations isn't used for anything else and normal CoNLL processors can't handle it, you'll probably have to write something custom.